# Excel Data Validation Combo box Click

Tags: vba, excel

I am very new to coding...

Sheet 1 has my data validation in a scroll list on it and sheet 2 has the list that it is validating the data from.  I am trying to make a combo box on sheet 1 that will auto fill while you type instead of having to type the exact name. The code below only works if the data list is on the same sheet as the sheet I am trying to make the combo box on.  Any idea how to change the code so it will pull from sheet 2 where all the list of data is located?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
'=========================================
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim str As String
Dim cboTemp As OLEObject
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
On Error GoTo errHandler

If Target.Count > 1 Then GoTo exitHandler

Set cboTemp = ws.OLEObjects("TempCombo")
  On Error Resume Next
If cboTemp.Visible = True Then
  With cboTemp
    .Top = 10
    .Left = 10
    .ListFillRange = ""
    .LinkedCell = ""
    .Visible = False
    .Value = ""
  End With
End If

  On Error GoTo errHandler
  If Target.Validation.Type = 3 Then
    'if the cell contains a data validation list
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    'get the data validation formula
    str = Target.Validation.Formula1
    str = Right(str, Len(str) - 1)
    With cboTemp
      'show the combobox with the list
      .Visible = True
      .Left = Target.Left
      .Top = Target.Top
      .Width = Target.Width + 15
      .Height = Target.Height + 5
      .ListFillRange = ws.Range(str).Address
      .LinkedCell = Target.Address
    End With
    cboTemp.Activate
    'open the drop down list automatically
    Me.TempCombo.DropDown 
  End If

exitHandler:
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.EnableEvents = True
  Exit Sub
errHandler:
  Resume exitHandler 

End Sub 
'====================================
'Optional code to move to next cell if Tab or Enter are pressed
'from code by Ted Lanham
'***NOTE: if KeyDown causes problems, change to KeyUp

Private Sub TempCombo_KeyDown(ByVal _
        KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, _
        ByVal Shift As Integer)
    Select Case KeyCode
        Case 9 'Tab 
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
        Case 13 'Enter 
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
        Case Else
            'do nothing
    End Select
End Sub
'====================================
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of code just to populate a Combobox in the active sheet.
Since you are using the Worksheet_Change event, you don't have to set the worksheet as the active sheet, it already is.
This sample code will populate ComboBox1 with a range of cells from Sheet2,
The code and Combobox1 are located in Sheet1.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ws As Worksheet, Rws As Long, Rng As Range
    'ComboBox1 and this code are in Sheet1
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2")    'sheet2 column 1 is the list to populate Combobox1

    With ws    'set the list range
        Rws = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(Rws, 1))
    End With

    With ComboBox1    'populate the combobox
        .Clear
        .List = Rng.Value
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can forgo the need to have Excel autocomplete based on a user's entry, you can use the cell validation as demonstrated here (backward compatible with older versions):

[Dependent Drop-down Lists](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/dependent-drop-down-lists.html)

Or here (for newer versions):

[Insert or delete a drop-down list](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/Insert-or-delete-a-drop-down-list-fdde2fb6-e257-4c62-b794-1427762428c6?CorrelationId=0411b436-e36e-4cfd-92ff-a457c31595c1&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

The upside to this is that it requires no code, unless you would like to manipulate the list automatically.

Using a combobox object is definitely more complicated, so you might skip on that until your coding catches up to the complexity required by objects.

**==EDIT==**

OK, then, 2 things: this code (Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)) applies every time you click a new cell.  If your values don't change very much you can make sure the cbo only populates on workbook_open, or something less active.  However, if the combobox source data changes frequently while the workbook is open then having a frequent refresh to the source would be worthwhile.

Try naming the range you want the combobox to get its data from and pointing the ListFillRange to that named range, like:

```
.ListFillRange = "myNamedRange"
```

Then, if your source grows or shrinks, incorporate code that redefines the named range based on the changes.

Comment: Yeah I understand simple validation, but the list I have is 400+ so scrolling through that each time is a pain.  That's why I was trying to figure out a way for it to auto populate while you typed.